# Populating form using saved data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First I need to disclose that I'm a major noob here...but I think I'm getting better! (in no small part thanks to the help of the stack overflow community :-D)

I've created a dynamically generated menu for project milestones.  It uses a table that allows the user to enter the date and description of each milestone and save them to a database.  Each time the user wants to enter a new milestone, they click a button to dynamically generate a new row.  (See picture for clarification: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/milestones_ex.png Note: the checkboxes are only used to delete rows right now)

That all works great so far.  The issue is that once the user saves their milestones, I want them to be able to revisit the page and modify their milestones or add more.  Obviously this requires the script to query the database and generate/populate the rows accordingly.

I cobbled together the following code to generate the form from the database but for some reason it crashes the page.  I've checked the error log and noting relevant seems to turn up.  I was wondering if anyone might see a glaring error with what I've got or be able to recommend an alternative method.  In case it helps, I'm writing this to be deployed as a plugin for wordpress.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
function upsmart_create_milestones_form() {
        global $wpdb;
        $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM upsmart_milestones WHERE wordpress_id=%d",get_current_user_id()),ARRAY_A);
        $months = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July ','August','September','October','November','December');
        echo <<<EOHTML
        <form method='post'>
            <h3>Project Milestones</h3>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://upsmart.com/wp-content/plugins/upsmart_sitemanager/js/create_business_milestone.js"></script>
            <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

            <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
EOHTML;
        foreach($data as $milestone){
          echo <<<EOHTML
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>\
                <td>
                    <select name="month[]">
EOHTML;
                foreach ($months as $month) {
                    if($month == $milestone->month){
                        echo <<<EOHTML
                        <option value="{$month}" selected>$month</option>
EOHTML;
                    continue;
                    }
                    echo <<<EOHTML
                    <option value="{$month}">$month</option>
EOHTML;
                }
                echo <<<EOHTML
                </select>
                <select name="day[]">
EOHTML;
                foreach (range(1, 31) as $day) {
                    if($month == $milestone->day){
                        echo <<<EOHTML
                        <option value="{$day}" selected>$day</option>
EOHTML;
                    }
                    echo <<<EOHTML
                    <option value="{$day}">{$day}</option>
EOHTML;
                }
                echo <<<EOHTML
                </select>
                <select name="year[]">
EOHTML;
                foreach (range(2013, 1990, -1) as $year) {
                    if($month == $milestone->year){
                        echo <<<EOHTML
                        <option value="{$year}" selected>$year</option>
EOHTML;
                    }
                    echo <<<EOHTML
                    <option value="{$year}">{$year}</option>
EOHTML;
                }
                echo <<<EOHTML
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="txt[]"/>$milestone->description</td>
            </tr>
EOHTML;
        } /* END FOR EACH LOOP ON MILESTONES */

    echo <<<EOHTML
        </table>
        <input type='submit' value='Save'/>
        </form>
EOHTML;
    }/* END FUNCTION */
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Consider a PHP Framework. I prefer [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) for it's inbuilt help which is always easy to access while working.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata The OP seems to be using WordPress.

Comment: @jeroen Ah yes, I'm using wordpress. Think that would that be important to disclose in this case?

Comment: @Sam Could be, but it seems you just have a simple syntax error at the `continue:` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your script:

```
            foreach ($months as $month) {
                if($month == $milestone->month){
                    echo <<<EOHTML
                    <option value="{$month}" selected>$month</option>
EOHTML;
                continue:
                        ^ This should be ; and not :
                }
                echo <<<EOHTML
                <option value="{$month}">$month</option>
EOHTML;
            }
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing; thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it but it's still not happy.  Given that mistake though, I'm guessing I might find some more if I look hard enough.  Overall does the structure of my code seem relatively sound?  I'm still figuring this whole php thing out.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Sam Hard to tell, I always find WordPress code a bit messy. I would probably use a variable to set the `selected` value to avoid code duplication and I would definitely get rid of the inline javascript and styling, but that is more html related than php related.

Comment: Turns out your answer was all I needed.  I'd formatted the code to enter it into this post using my text editor and forgot to set it back to where it was.  Once I did that and implemented your syntax suggestion, I was set.  Thanks so much for your help.